# automatic spacing between words in math mode

Tags: math-mode, spacing

In math mode, something like `$if f x > 3 then 42 else y$` typesets to this:
[image: $if f x > 3 then 42 else y$]

Obviously, spacing is wrong here, and I need to correct manually:
`$if \: f \: x > 3 \: then \: 42 \: else \: y$` typesets to 
[image]

1. Which is the correct amount of space to insert?
2. Is there a way to automate this process, i.e. automatically insert a space between "words" separates by spaces in the source?

Comment: Please read some LaTeX tutorial before you start typing, e.g., http://tobi.oetiker.ch/lshort/lshort.pdf chapter 3.

Comment: I'm not new to LaTeX - just new to functional-programming-style expressions in math mode :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

the spacing is the least of the problems, the letters are all wrong as well. The math italic font has wide side-bearings specifically so that adjacent letters do *not* look like letters forming a word but rather the usual mathematical use as implied multiplication of separate variables. To use a multi-letter identifier you need to use a text font, then inter-word spacing will automatically work as well, although you would need to use `\quad` or a similar space if embedding the text in math mode..

```
if  $f x > 3$  then $42$  else $y$
```

or if you need to embed it in display math

```
\[ \textrm{if} \quad f x > 3 \quad \textrm{then} \quad 42  \textrm{else} \quad y \]
```

Comment: Which spacing would you use for `$f x$`?

Comment: @felix-freiberger: What is `f x`? Do you mean `f(x)`?

Comment: @felix-freiberger sorry I dropped the f by mistake, babara just put them back so see edited answer.

Comment: `f x` is a functional application in a functional programming language like Haskell.

Comment: @felix-freiberger either `fx` as above or perhaps `\mathop{f{}}x` which would give the same spacing as a mult-letter identifier like `\log`

Comment: `\mathop{f{}}x` looks OK (and quite similar to `f \, x`), but is _really_ long to type. Even `\,` and `\mathrm` make a formula really unreadable in the source pretty fast: `\textrm{Single} \; (\textrm{Iso} \; a \; b) \rightsquigarrow b \; ()`. Isn't there a better / more readable way?

Comment: you would never type `\mathop{f{}}x` in the actual document,  make a macro for function application just as you use `\log` not `\mathop{\mathrm{log}}`

Comment: Ouch - a `\mathop` doesn't give you any additional space before a `(` - which makes sense in math, but doesn't make sense in functional programming...

Comment: I'd suggest `\text` instead of all those `\mathrm`; or even `\[\mbox{...}\]` with embedded `$`

Comment: @fefrei Is it really math mode you want? Or do you really want monospace type, with, e.g., `\verb` or the `verbatim` environment? The latter is more often used for code...

Comment: @ChrisWhite I'm not actually writing Haskell code - it's a Haskell-inspired mathematical notation used for [equational reasoning](http://www.cs.tufts.edu/~nr/comp150fp/archive/ralf-hinze/just-do-it.pdf).